# Google reCaptcha reset doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, reload, reset, recaptcha

I want to reset Google reCaptcha widget when I submit my form via AJAX and have some input errors or form is sent. I'm using multiple widgets on the same page so I render these widgets explicitly.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha-1"></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha-2"></div>
...
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha-20"></div>
```

Loading widget

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=en" async defer></script>
<script>
    var reCaptchaCallback = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var id = elements[i].getAttribute('id');
            grecaptcha.render(id, {
                'sitekey' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

After submit form:

```
var id = $('.g-recaptcha', form).attr('id');
grecaptcha.reset(id);
```

Form is the instance of the submitted form.

Everything works fine when form is fill correctly. But reCaptcha doesn't reset or reload.
It try this `grecaptcha.reset()` but no results.

Any idea?

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(. I have no errors. It looks like it reload the whole `recaptcha.js` file again.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `grecaptcha.reset()` method accepts an optional `widget_id` parameter, and  defaults to the first widget created if unspecified. A `widget_id` is returned from the `grecaptcha.render()` method for each widget created. So you need to store this id, and use it to reset that specific widget:

```
var widgetId = grecaptcha.render(container);
grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
```

[See here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api).

Comment: Many thanks, I hope that this will works but not. I must doing something wrong. I have update my code. Maybe it helps. I'm now getting error: `Invalid ReCAPTCHA client id: recaptcha-1`. Don't understand why the ID is wrong.

Comment: @quarky you need to store the value returned by `grecaptcha.render`, and perhaps attach it to the element. eg: `var id = grecaptcha.render(etc);  elements[i].setAttribute('cid', id);` and then use that id for removal.

Comment: thank you very much. Yes that was the problem. Now it is working fine. Many thanks.

Comment: Just in case anyone is going to be checking the ID, it is a zero-based index. Therefore, ``(!widgetId)`` can be false if the widget exists.

Comment: grecaptcha.render(container); always return 0 as id, what wrong?

Comment: To answer Oleg, it's a zero-based index, so the first recaptcha widget will always return 0 as the ID.  It's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong id.

`$('.g-recaptcha', form).attr('id');`

Your selector will capture all 20 reCaptcha widget, but only return a single DOM id (the first reCaptcha). So your code is actually resetting the first recaptcha.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by other answers here, `reset()` method defaults to the first widget when there are multiple on the same page, and the API doesn't offer a simple or reliable way to find the widget Id in code. A solution to this is to load widgets explicitly and store the widget Id in a data attribute

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaLoaded&render=explicit"></script>

<script>
    function recaptchaLoaded() {
    
        document.querySelectorAll('.g-recaptcha').forEach((el, i) => {
            var widgetId = grecaptcha.render(el);
            el.setAttribute('data-grecaptcha-id', widgetId);
        });
    
    }

    document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        var widgetId = document.getElementById("mycaptcha").getAttribute('data-grecaptcha-id');
        grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
    });

</script>
```

Note that the script URL must include render=explicit and the name of your onload callback method

Answer (score 0):

Just edited your code to create a dynamic widget.

```
<script>
    var reCaptchaCallback = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {                
            widgetId+i = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha-'+i, {
                'sitekey' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

And after you have successfully completed the above task, change in the AJAX success: response

```
grecaptcha.reset(widgetId+id);
```

Here the id would be the same that is generated from the below for Loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have two google captcha in same page, two different form

```
<form id="form1">    
<input type="text" name="form1-input">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
</form>
```

and

```
<form id="form2">    
<input type="text" name="form2-input">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
</form>
```

You can reset first captcha by

```
 grecaptcha.reset(); or grecaptcha.reset(0);
```

And Second Captcha by index (1)

```
grecaptcha.reset(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where there were multiple recaptchas on the page, some were hidden. In this case I had to loop through all of them and reset them like this:

```
                var count = 0;
                $(".g-recaptcha").each(function () {
                    grecaptcha.reset(count);
                    count++;
                });
```